# Java class's field dynamic cast

Tags: java, class, inheritance, model-view-controller, properties

I'm working on my abstract swt mvc controller noob-class:

Here are code's snippets:

```
public abstract class Controller {
    protected View view;

    public Controller(View v) {
        view = v;
    }

    protected void render() {
        data();
        view.setData(data);
        view.render();
        listeners();
        if (display)
            view.open();
    }
    protected void data() {}

    protected void listeners() {}
}
```

AboutController.java (represends new window):

```
public class AboutController extends Controller {

    public AboutController() {
        super(new AboutView());
        super.render();
    }
}
```

And I've faced with an obstacle: in abstract contoller i have a field View view, but it's child classes can represend a sub-class of View (like AboutView that extends View), and I cant access to non-View fields and methods (that are new in AboutView).

Can i clarify the class's field view in it's child-classes?

I understand that most likely this is a bug in my classes's architecture, but i cant figure out what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best / most idiomatic way is to use *[Generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/)*.

```
public abstract class Controller<T extends View> {
    protected T view;

    public Controller(T v) {
        view = v;
    }

    protected void render() {
        data();
        view.setData(data);
        view.render();
        listeners();
        if (display)
            view.open();
    }
    protected void data() {}

    protected void listeners() {}
}

public class AboutController extends Controller<AboutView> {

    public AboutController() {
        super(new AboutView());
        super.render();
    }

    public void doSomething() {
        view.getAboutStuff();
    }
}
```

Comment: It's amazing how so obvious solution escapes from the mind. Big thanks to you!